# linux deployment from windows Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, package

I'm developing my java application in Eclipse under a windows environment, my target system is linux and when I compile it on the linux box I find that I need to remove the

```
    package com.myname.application;
```

from each of my .java files. The Eclipse IDE requires them to be there otherwise it doesnt compile. How can I get around this as its a pain to remove all before compiling under linux.

EDIT:
When compiling under linux I get a "cannot find symbol" before I remove the code, removing it solves the problem

Thanks

Comment: If your classes are in that package, you shouldn't need to remove them.  What is the exact error message that you're seeing that's forcing you to remove them?

Comment: if you maintain proper directory structure between machines (win-dev, linux-compile), there should not be any problems. Can you gives us more information about what eclipse IDE complains?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: i get MultiThreadChatServer.java:19: cannot find symbol when compiling in linux

Comment: Thanks @Jayan I have editted my question